# (C# Monogame) When adding objects to a list, keyboard input lags for a frame

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

Basically, I have a list of enemy objects and timed events using `gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalSeconds`. Every 0.1 seconds it calls upon a method to check for enemy spawns, and if we're at second 2.5 we add an enemy to the enemy list.

Now what happens is that keyboard input lags for a second, for example, if i'm moving continuously to the left, my character will stop for a short period (like 0.1 secs i think) before resuming moving.

I'm using gameTime to check for keyboard input every millisecond, but i've tried not using it too and it still happens. It's also weird because I have code that creates bullet objects every 0.5 seconds if i hold down Z the same way it does with enemies (through adding the object to a list), but that doesn't make it lagg the input

```
if (elapsedMs > oldElapsedMs + 0.001) //Millisecond update, for movement
        {
            oldElapsedMs = elapsedMs;

            //Keys to be held down.
            newState = Keyboard.GetState();
            Keys[] pressed_Key = Keyboard.GetState().GetPressedKeys();
            for (int i = 0; i < pressed_Key.Length; i++)
            {
                switch (pressed_Key[i])
                {
                    case Keys.Escape:
                        this.Exit();
                        break;
                    case Keys.Left:
                        player.tryMoveLeft();
                        break;
                    case Keys.Right:
                        player.tryMoveRight();
                        break;
                    case Keys.Up:
                        player.tryMoveUp();
                        break;
                    case Keys.Down:
                        player.tryMoveDown();
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Spawn check code:

```
//0.1sec Update, spawning code
        if (elapsedSpawnTime > oldElapsedSpawnTime + 0.1)
        {
            oldElapsedSpawnTime = elapsedSpawnTime;
            spawnTimer += 1; //Every 0.1 sec add one to spawnTimer. The spawn timer int is what stage.Spawn() uses to check for spawns.
            stage.Spawn();


        }
```

my spawning method in my stage class:

```
public void Spawn()
    {
        switch (game.spawnTimer) //Each int is 0.1sec
        {
            //10 spawnTimer = 1 Second

            case 40:
            case 42:
            case 44:
            case 46:
                game.enemyList.Add(new Enemy(game.enemySprite, 500, 500, 1, true));
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Thanks. If you want to help me but need more info you can add my skype @ emil1000123

Comment: Please post the actual code instead of screenshots.

Comment: Just did. Sorry

Comment: Is your enemy class a reference type or a value type?   Avoid calling `new` on any classes in the middle of a game loop. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnhar/2007/07/02/twin-paths-to-garbage-collector-nirvana/. Excerpt:

do not call new on reference types. It is ok to new value types such as Matrix, Vector3, and Color, however.

Any time you find yourself wanting to new a reference type, use an object pool to reuse existing instances instead. The Particle and Audio 3D samples on creators.xna.com use this technique, and SwampThingTom blogged about a reusable pool collection.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the screenshot says

```
( elapsedMs > oldElapsedMs + 0.001 )
```

The variable names tell that those values are in milliseconds, so are you are checking every 0.001 milliseconds?

Comment: No, just bad naming. elapsedMs = gameTime.TotalGameTime.Seconds.
Basically it's a float that contains second + milliseconds.
It checks if the gametime is 1 millisecond more than last oldElapsedMs

Comment: You could use a stopwatch to measure how long your calculations on each frame take. That way you can find out, if its a piece of code that takes a lot longer than you'd expect. Btw. do you GC.Collect() on every frame or can it do its job whenever it likes?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue lies in the millisecond update:

```
if (elapsedMs > oldElapsedMs + 0.001)
```

So, what happens if it gets at this statement, but havn't passed 1 millisecond yet?

A computer looks at code in ticks, those are way faster than milliseconds, and thus it'll ignore that statement at all, which can result in a tiny lag, depending on your PC's performance and file size (which will increase by adding arrays or lists)

Now, I don't know what you've used in the TryMoveLeft() (ect.) methodes. But I think you're better of my getting rid of the said if-statement. and try to rework the way how you player walks.

Maybe I might give a few tips if I can see how the player.TryMoveRight method looks like.